# Sequelize - Not quite getting the correct results from a many to many select

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm fairly new to Sequelize, but not to SQL.  But I'm really struggling with how to correctly get my results from a many to many relationship.

My Schema:
[image: My Schema]

So I need to get all the Sheets with a given vendor_id and a given chemical_id.

Here is my Sequelize that is close but not quite producing the right query.

```
GetVendorFiles: async function(args) {
            console.log('args: ', args);
            if (!args.vendor_id) {
                throw new Error('Invalid argument: vendor_id');
            }
            let chemical_id = '';
            let load_id = '';

            if (args.load) {
                // first get the load id
                load_id = await db.Load.findOne({
                    attributes: ['id'],
                    where: { value: args.load }
                }).then((r) => console.log('load id: ', r));
            } else if (args.chemical) {
                // first get the load id
                chemical_id = await db.Chemical.findOne({
                    attributes: ['id'],
                    where: { name: args.chemical }
                }).then((r) => {
                    return r.dataValues.id;
                });
            }

            return await db.Vendor.findOne({
                where: { id: args.vendor_id }
            }).then(async function(vendor) {
                // build the include block conditionally based on whether
                // a chemical or load was passed in
                const model =
                    load_id !== ''
                        ? db.Load
                        : chemical_id !== ''
                        ? db.Load
                        : db.Sheet;
                const includeBlock = [
                    {
                        model: db.Load,
                        required: true,
                        as: 'Load',
                        // where: { id: load_id },
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: db.Chemical,
                                required: true,
                                as: 'chemicals',
                                where: { id: chemical_id }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ];
                const files = await db.Sheet.findAll({
                    attributes: ['sheet_name', 'sheet_file_name'],
                    include: includeBlock,
                    model: model,
                    where: {
                        deleted_at: null,
                        vendor_id: vendor.dataValues.id
                    }
                });
                if (files) {
                    return files;
                }
                return null;
            });
        },
```

And here is the query it is producing:

```
SELECT `Sheet`.`id`, `Sheet`.`sheet_name`, `Sheet`.`sheet_file_name`, `chemicals`.`id` AS `chemicals.id`, `chemicals`.`name` AS `chemicals.name`, `chemicals`.`created_at` AS `chemicals.created_at`, `chemicals`.`updated_at` AS `chemicals.updated_a
t`, `chemicals`.`deleted_at` AS `chemicals.deleted_at`, `chemicals`.`created_at` AS `chemicals.createdAt`, `chemicals`.`updated_at` AS `chemicals.updatedAt`, `chemicals`.`deleted_at` AS `chemicals.deletedAt`, `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads`.`created_at` AS `chemicals
.chemicals_to_loads.createdAt`, `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads`.`updated_at` AS `chemicals.chemicals_to_loads.updatedAt`, `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads`.`load_id` AS `chemicals.chemicals_to_loads.load_id`, `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads`.`chemical_id` AS `chemicals.
chemicals_to_loads.ChemicalId` FROM `sheets` AS `Sheet` INNER JOIN ( `chemicals_to_loads` AS `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads` INNER JOIN `chemicals` AS `chemicals` ON `chemicals`.`id` = `chemicals->chemicals_to_loads`.`chemical_id`) ON `Sheet`.`id` = `chemicals->chemi
cals_to_loads`.`load_id` AND (`chemicals`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `chemicals`.`id` = 24) WHERE (`Sheet`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (`Sheet`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `Sheet`.`vendor_id` = '157'));
```

Towards the end it says `ON Sheet.id = chemicals->chemicals_to_loads.load_id` and I learned I simply need to change that `Sheet.id` to `Sheet.load_id` and everything works perfect!  But how do I get the Sequelize to do that?

**Update:**  Here is some troubleshooting I have done to try and fix it but to no avail.  I thought I might need to properly define the foreign key in the Sheets table.  So in my index.js under models where I am doing a lot of my associations, I added the foreignKey option to this line:

```
// Sheets- foreign key in sheets table "belongs to" loads table
db.Sheet.belongsTo(db.Load, { foreignKey: 'load_id' });
```

Unfortunately, that did not seem to have any effect.

**Update 2:** I am adding in the 'associate' sections of the Chemical and Load models if that helps at all.
Chemicals.js (just the associate section):

```
Chemicals.associate = (models) => {
        Chemicals.belongsToMany(models.Load, {
            through: 'chemicals_to_loads',
            as: 'loads',
            foreignKey: 'chemical_id',
            otherKey: 'load_id'
        });
    };

    Chemicals.associate = (models) => {
        Chemicals.belongsToMany(models.Vendor, {
            through: 'vendors_to_chemicals',
            as: 'vendors',
            foreignKey: 'chemical_id'
        });
```

Loads.js (just the associate section):

```
    Loads.associate = (models) => {
        Loads.belongsToMany(models.Chemical, {
            through: 'chemicals_to_loads',
            as: 'chemicals',
            foreignKey: 'load_id',
            otherKey: 'chemical_id'
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M:N you have to  specify other key in M:N

```
Product.belongsToMany(Category, {
  through: 'product_categories',
  foreignKey: 'objectId', // replaces `productId`
  otherKey: 'typeId' // replaces `categoryId`
});
Category.belongsToMany(Product, {
  through: 'product_categories',
  foreignKey: 'typeId', // replaces `categoryId`
  otherKey: 'objectId' // replaces `productId`
});
```

ref https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html

Comment: I tried doing that.  Now am getting this error: `Error: Unknown attribute "load_id" passed as targetKey, define this attribute on model "Load" first`

Comment: `load_id` is in my auto-created join table `chemicals_to_loads`, it is not in the Load model.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.  Loads.BelongsToMany(Chemical) and Chemical.BelongsToMany(Load)

Comment: Unless I'm doing it wrong, that didn't seem to help.  I have added in my modified associates into my question.

Comment: Or do I need to let Sequelize recreate those tables and associations from the start?

Comment: i see what are you try to do now. Are you still using the same GetVendor files? .But  basically you can't include chemical in sheet u have to nested include chemical in load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219114/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-anonymouze).